# Regex working in C# but not in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help getting a piece of regex working in javascript please?

This is the regular expression:

```
storify.com\/*(?<code>[^"]*)
```

It works fine in C# but I can't get it working in js, I presume due to a delimiter issue but not sure which characters are causing the problem.

This is the js I'm trying but gives me and an "invalid quanitifier" error on the first line

```
var myregex = /storify.com\/*(?<code>[^"]*)/;
var storify = 'http://storify.com/DigitalFirst/ces-2013-five-things-you-missed-day-3';
var remoteid = storify.match(myregex);
console.log(remoteid);
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help get this working.

Comment: You should escape the `.`.  Also, you probably want `.*`, not `/*`.

Comment: Could you post your C# code?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript regexes have no suport for named captures `(?<xxx>...)`, that is why.

More details [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) (note: JavaScript is referred to as ECMA [262, to be precise]).